# How to create a passwordResetLink using the Firebase admin API?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying customize the user experience in my firebase project and hence as well need to create custom email templates including the necessary action links.

Unfortunately I'm unable to get my firebase cloud function to create the `passwordResetLink`. No matter what I try the function doesn't seem to be valid despite being setup according to the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links).

Error: auth.generatePasswordResetLink is not a function

I tried to reinstall the node_modules as well already but without any success :(

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const auth = admin.auth();
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports = module.exports = functions.https.onCall((data) => {

    const email = data.email
    const actionCodeSettings = {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        handleCodeInApp: false
    };

    auth.generatePasswordResetLink(email, actionCodeSettings)
        .then((link) => {
        // return link
        return { link: link }
    })
        .catch((error) => {
        // Some error occurred.
    });

})
```

The function above should simply return the `passwordResetLink` so I can work with it afterwards to create a custom email template.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an old version of `firebase-admin`. The API you're trying to invoke was added in v6.2.0 of the SDK. Make sure you have at least that version.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been trying for hours to get it to work but of course missed to update the npm modules... Works like a charm now :)